# Prove this function has at most two zero points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function on the interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $f''(x)>f(x)$ for all $x$. Prove that $f$ has at most two zero points.

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction,but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 10):

If $f$ has more than 2 zeros, then so does $e^{-x}f(x)=g(x)$. Then by the Rolle's theorem, $$h(x)=e^xg'(x)=f'(x)-f(x)$$ should have at least 2 zeros. But then $e^xh(x)$ has at least 2 zeros, which contradicts $$[e^xh(x)]'=e^x(h'(x)+h(x))=e^x(f''(x)-f(x))>0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!tailihaile!